# Why deviceManger.lockNow() don't off screen

Tags: kotlin

I try to turn off screen android use `deviceManger.lockNow()` but it is don't off,this is my code:

**DeviceAdmin.kt**

```
package org.deepspeechdemo

import android.app.admin.DeviceAdminReceiver
import android.content.Context
import android.content.Intent
import android.util.Log

class DeviceAdmin : DeviceAdminReceiver(){
    override fun onEnabled(context: Context, intent: Intent) {
        super.onEnabled(context, intent)
        Log.i("DeviceAdmin","Enable")
    }

    override fun onDisabled(context: Context, intent: Intent) {
        super.onDisabled(context, intent)
        Log.i("DeviceAdmin","disable")
    }
}
```

**MainActivity**

```
package org.deepspeechdemo

import android.Manifest
import android.app.ActivityManager
import android.content.pm.PackageManager
import android.media.AudioFormat
import android.media.AudioRecord
import android.media.MediaRecorder
import android.os.Build
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.View
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*
import org.deepspeech.libdeepspeech.DeepSpeechModel
import java.io.File
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicBoolean
import java.util.Arrays
import java.lang.StringBuilder
import android.content.Intent
import android.app.Service
import android.app.admin.DevicePolicyManager
import android.content.ComponentName
import android.content.Context
import android.util.Log

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private var model: DeepSpeechModel? = null
    private var transcriptionThread: Thread? = null
    private var isRecording: AtomicBoolean = AtomicBoolean(false)
    lateinit var compName: ComponentName
    private val TFLITE_MODEL_FILENAME = "deepspeech-0.9.3-models.tflite"
    private val SCORER_FILENAME = "deepspeech-0.9.3-models.scorer"
    lateinit var deviceManger: DevicePolicyManager
    val listOfObjects=arrayOf("just")
    private fun checkAudioPermission() {
        // Permission is automatically granted on SDK < 23 upon installation.
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
            val permission = Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO

            if (checkSelfPermission(permission) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, arrayOf(permission), 3)
            }
        }
    }
    private fun transcribe() {
        // We read from the recorder in chunks of 2048 shorts. With a model that expects its input
        // at 16000Hz, this corresponds to 2048/16000 = 0.128s or 128ms.
        val audioBufferSize = 2048
        val audioData = ShortArray(audioBufferSize)
        deviceManger=getSystemService(DEVICE_POLICY_SERVICE) as DevicePolicyManager
        runOnUiThread { btnStartInference.text = "Stop Recording" }
        compName= ComponentName(this, DeviceAdmin::class.java)
        val enable=deviceManger.isAdminActive(compName)
        model?.let { model ->
            val streamContext = model.createStream()

            val recorder = AudioRecord(
                MediaRecorder.AudioSource.VOICE_RECOGNITION,
                model.sampleRate(),
                AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO,
                AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT,
                audioBufferSize
            )
            recorder.startRecording()

            while (isRecording.get()) {
                recorder.read(audioData, 0, audioBufferSize)
                model.feedAudioContent(streamContext, audioData, audioData.size)
                var decoded = model.intermediateDecode(streamContext)
                runOnUiThread { transcription.text = decoded }
                val array: Array<String> = decoded.split(" ").toTypedArray()
//                for (i in array){
//                Log.d("aaa",i)}
                val found = Arrays.stream(array).anyMatch { t -> t == "just" }
                if (found){
                    val am = this.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE) as ActivityManager?
                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                        val appTasks = am!!.getAppTasks()
                        if (appTasks.size > 0) {
                            val appTask = appTasks.get(0)
                            appTask.finishAndRemoveTask()
                        }
                    }
                    deviceManger.lockNow()}

            }

            val decoded = model.finishStream(streamContext)

            runOnUiThread {
                btnStartInference.text = "Start Recording"
                transcription.text = decoded
            }

            recorder.stop()
            recorder.release()
        }
    }

    private fun createModel(): Boolean {
        val modelsPath = getExternalFilesDir(null).toString()
        val tfliteModelPath = "$modelsPath/$TFLITE_MODEL_FILENAME"
        val scorerPath = "$modelsPath/$SCORER_FILENAME"

        for (path in listOf(tfliteModelPath, scorerPath)) {
            if (!File(path).exists()) {
                status.append("Model creation failed: $path does not exist.\n")
                return false
            }
        }

        model = DeepSpeechModel(tfliteModelPath)
        model?.enableExternalScorer(scorerPath)

        return true
    }

    private fun startListening() {
        if (isRecording.compareAndSet(false, true)) {
            transcriptionThread = Thread(Runnable { transcribe() }, "Transcription Thread")
            transcriptionThread?.start()
        }
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        checkAudioPermission()

        // Create application data directory on the device
        val modelsPath = getExternalFilesDir(null).toString()

        status.text = "Ready. Copy model files to \"$modelsPath\" if running for the first time.\n"
    }

    private fun stopListening() {
        isRecording.set(false)
    }

    fun onRecordClick(v: View?) {
        if (model == null) {
            if (!createModel()) {
                return
            }
            status.append("Created model.\n")
        }

        if (isRecording.get()) {
            stopListening()
        } else {
            startListening()
        }
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
        if (model != null) {
            model?.freeModel()
        }
    }
}
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="org.deepspeechdemo">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:excludeFromRecents="true"
            android:noHistory="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <receiver
            android:name=".DeviceAdmin"
            android:description="@string/app_name"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:permission="android.permission.BIND_DEVICE_ADMIN">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.app.action.DEVICE_ADMIN_ENABLED" />
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.app.device_admin"
                android:resource="@xml/policies" />
        </receiver>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**policies.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<device-admin xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <uses-policies>
        <force-lock/>
    </uses-policies>
</device-admin>
```

After run app , in the specified case `if (found)`(line 77,MainActivity.kt) app wil stop run but screen don't turn off:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/muMB6.jpg)

Thank everyone!

Comment: I already know the problem, when I launch the app it doesn't ask why to ask to enable administrator rights

Comment: Why does the application not ask for admin?